# How to format chapters and sections using memoir

Tags: sectioning, chapters, memoir

I’m formatting my thesis and I have to use the following guidelines in each chapter and subsections’ names:

**PRIMARY SECTION**: Bold and capitalized

**Secondary Section**: Bold and initial letters capitalized with 1,0 cm indentation

**Tertiary section**: Bold and only the first letter capitalized with 1,5 cm indentation

*Quaternary Section*: italics and initial letters capitalized with 2,0 cm indentation

*Quinary section*: italics and only the first letter capitalized with 2,5 cm identation

How do I do this using memoir?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some work on the titles yourself but:

```
% memdivsprob.tex  SE 579920

\documentclass{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}

\setsecindent{1.0cm} \setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\setsubsecindent{1.5cm} \setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecindent{2.0cm} \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\itshape}
\setparaindent{2.5cm}  \setparaheadstyle{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one (primary)}
\section{Section one (secondary)}
\subsection{Subsection one (tertiary)}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one (quaternary)}
\paragraph{Paragraph one (quinary)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will have to capitalize, or not, the letters in the titles according to the guidelines.